# Can you check if an npm version number is valid before running npm publish?

Tags: node.js, npm, continuous-integration

Obviously if you try to `npm publish` without updating the version number of your module you will get an error.  Is there any way to verify that the version number is valid for publishing before actually running `npm publish`?

My use case: I'm using CircleCI to build my module when pushing to any git branch.  If somebody creates a pull request to master, I want to verify that the version number has been updated.  However, I don't want to actually publish the package until the pull request to master has been accepted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get your current package version by: `npm view <pkg> version` (npm v5), than compare it with the version in the code.

It is easy to check whether the version has change, a simple `===` is enough. If you need to check whether the new version is valid, you should use look for a module for that.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver for example if you use JS code to check, or https://github.com/cloudflare/semver_bash if you use bash